# Rails controller receives all parameters, but fails to create the database record correctly

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, arel

I'm going to get straight to the point, which is that according to my log file, when I submit a form to create a new record, all of the parameters are sent correctly, but some attributes fail to be set when creating the record in the database.  Following is the pertinent log entry:

```
Started POST "/computers" for 192.168.8.70 at 2011-05-19 16:24:31 -0400
  Processing by ComputersController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"agR6MrYbMTbXeR9+Oit0rUzrhcKuhg6p/jpGqQD9MhI=", "show_location_buttons"=>"1", "computer"=>{"vendor_id"=>"1", "new_vendor_name"=>"", "model"=>"Hello", "hostname"=>"Hello", "user_id"=>"", "computer_type"=>"Desktop", "serial_number"=>"", "unh_id"=>"", "doc_id"=>"", "federal"=>"0", "department_id"=>"", "new_department_name"=>"", "security_id"=>"", "purchase_price"=>"", "purchase_date"=>"05/11/2011", "warranty_expiration"=>"05/28/2011", "activity_id"=>"", "new_activity_code"=>"", "condition_id"=>"", "new_condition_name"=>"", "location_id"=>"", "operating_system"=>"Fedora Core", "comments"=>""}, "commit"=>"Create Computer"}
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 48 LIMIT 1
  SQL (0.1ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.4ms)  SHOW TABLES
  Computer Load (0.2ms)  SELECT `computers`.`id` FROM `computers` WHERE (`computers`.`hostname` = BINARY 'Hello') LIMIT 1
  Vendor Load (0.1ms)  SELECT `vendors`.* FROM `vendors` WHERE `vendors`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
  SQL (0.7ms)  describe `computers`
  AREL (0.3ms)  INSERT INTO `computers` (`vendor_id`, `model`, `hostname`, `computer_type`, `serial_number`, `unh_id`, `doc_id`, `federal`, `department_id`, `security_id`, `purchase_price`, `purchase_date`, `warranty_expiration`, `activity_id`, `condition_id`, `location_id`, `operating_system`, `license_sticker_id`, `comments`, `created_at`, `updated_at`, `user_id`, `delta`) VALUES (1, 'Hello', 'Hello', 'Desktop', '', '', '', 0, NULL, NULL, NULL, '2011-11-05', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 'Fedora Core', NULL, '', '2011-05-19 20:24:31', '2011-05-19 20:24:31', NULL, 1)
```

If you look closely, the parameter for 'warranty_expiration' was set in the parameters hash, but if you look at the AREL line in the log, the insert into the database drops the value of the warranty_expiration field and inserts NULL.  I'm completely dumbfounded by this.  Any thoughts?

Following is my model and controller code for the Computer resource:

computer.rb

```
  class Computer < ActiveRecord::Base
    before_validation :format_fields

    validates :model, :presence => true
    validates :hostname, :presence => true, :uniqueness => true, :format => { :with => /^[a-zA-Z0-9]{3,25}$/ }
    validates :computer_type, :presence => true
    validates :operating_system, :presence => true

    validate :required_fields_specified

    belongs_to :vendor
    belongs_to :department
    belongs_to :security
    belongs_to :activity
    belongs_to :condition
    belongs_to :location
    belongs_to :license_sticker
    belongs_to :user

    has_many :hardware_addresses, :as => :addressable
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :hardware_addresses, :allow_destroy => true, :reject_if => lambda { |attr| attr[:mac_address].blank? }

    has_many :license_stickers, :dependent => :destroy
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :license_stickers, :allow_destroy => true, :reject_if => lambda { |attr| attr[:key].blank? or attr[:operating_system].blank? }

    has_many :pictures, :as => :imageable, :dependent => :destroy
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :pictures, :allow_destroy => true

    attr_accessor :new_vendor_name
    attr_accessor :new_activity_code
    attr_accessor :new_department_name
    attr_accessor :new_condition_name

    before_save :create_vendor_from_name
    before_save :create_activity_from_code
    before_save :create_department_from_name
    before_save :create_condition_from_name

    OPERATING_SYSTEMS = ["Microsoft Windows XP x86", "Microsoft Windows 7 x86", "Microsoft Windows Server 2003",
                         "Microsoft Windows XP x64", "Microsoft Windows 7 x64", "Microsoft Windows Server 2008 x86",
                         "Microsoft Windows Vista x86", "Microsoft Windows Vista x64", "Microsoft Windows Server 2008 x64",
                         "Ubuntu 8.x", "Ubuntu 9.x", "Ubuntu 10.x", "Fedora Core", "CentOS 5.x x86", "CentOS 4 x86", "IRIX",
                         "MacOS 10.5", "MacOS 10.6", "MacOS 10.7","CentOS 4 x64", "CentOS 5 x64", "ESX 3", "ESX 4", "SUSE"]

    COMPUTER_TYPES = ["Desktop","Laptop","Server"]

    def required_fields_specified
      errors.add_to_base "Specify an existing vendor, or create one." if vendor.blank? and new_vendor_name.blank?
    end

    def create_vendor_from_name
      create_vendor(:name => new_vendor_name) unless new_vendor_name.blank?
    end

    def create_activity_from_code
      create_activity(:code => new_activity_code) unless new_activity_code.blank?
    end

    def create_department_from_name
      create_department(:name => new_department_name) unless new_department_name.blank?
    end

    def create_condition_from_name
      create_condition(:name => new_condition_name) unless new_condition_name.blank?
    end

    def format_fields
      serial_number.upcase!
      hostname.capitalize!
      self.model = self.model.titleize
      unh_id.upcase!
      doc_id.upcase!
    end

    define_index do
      indexes vendor(:name), :as => :vendor_name, :sortable => true
      indexes model, :sortable => true
      indexes hostname, :sortable => true
      indexes computer_type, :sortable => true
      indexes serial_number, :as => :serial, :sortable => true
      indexes operating_system, :as => :os, :sortable => true
      indexes activity(:code), :as => :activity_code
      indexes condition(:name), :as => :condition_name
      indexes department(:name), :as => :department_name
      indexes license_sticker(:key), :as => :license_key
      indexes license_sticker(:operating_system), :as => :licensed_os

      has warranty_expiration, :as => :warranty
      set_property :delta => true
    end

  end
```

computers_controller.rb

```
class ComputersController < ApplicationController
  filter_access_to :all

  # GET /computers
  # GET /computers.xml
  def index
    @computers = Computer.search params[:search], :order => sort_column("computer_type"), :sort_mode => sort_direction,
      :per_page => 20, :page => params[:page], :star => true

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.js
      format.xml  { render :xml => @computers }
    end
  end

  # GET /computers/1
  # GET /computers/1.xml
  def show
    @computer = Computer.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @computer }
    end
  end

  # GET /computers/new
  # GET /computers/new.xml
  def new
    @computer = Computer.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @computer }
    end
  end

  # GET /computers/1/edit
  def edit
    @computer = Computer.find(params[:id])
  end

  # POST /computers
  # POST /computers.xml
  def create
    @computer = Computer.new(params[:computer])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @computer.save
        format.html { redirect_to(@computer, :notice => 'Computer was successfully created.') }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @computer, :status => :created, :location => @computer }
      else
        format.html { render :action => "new" }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @computer.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PUT /computers/1
  # PUT /computers/1.xml
  def update
    @computer = Computer.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @computer.update_attributes(params[:computer])
        format.html { redirect_to(@computer, :notice => 'Computer was successfully updated.') }
        format.xml  { head :ok }
      else
        format.html { render :action => "edit" }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @computer.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /computers/1
  # DELETE /computers/1.xml
  def destroy
    @computer = Computer.find(params[:id])
    @computer.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to(computers_url) }
      format.xml  { head :ok }
    end
  end

  private

  # def sort_column
  #   params[:sort] || "computer_type"
  # end

  # def sort_direction
  #   if params[:direction].nil?
  #     :asc
  #   else
  #     params[:direction].to_sym
  #   end
  # end
end
```

UPDATE: Result from executing requested line in rails console below.

> ruby-1.9.2-p180 :002 >
>   Computer.create! "vendor_id"=>"1",
>   "new_vendor_name"=>"",
>   "model"=>"Hello", "hostname"=>"Heo",
>   "user_id"=>"",
>   "computer_type"=>"Desktop",
>   "serial_number"=>"", "unh_id"=>"",
>   "doc_id"=>"", "federal"=>"0",
>   "department_id"=>"",
>   "new_department_name"=>"",
>   "security_id"=>"",
>   "purchase_price"=>"",
>   "purchase_date"=>"05/11/2011",
>   "warranty_expiration"=>"05/28/2011",
>   "activity_id"=>"",
>   "new_activity_code"=>"",
>   "condition_id"=>"",
>   "new_condition_name"=>"",
>   "location_id"=>"",
>   "operating_system"=>"Fedora Core",
>   "comments"=>"" Sphinx 0.9.9-release
>   (r2117) Copyright (c) 2001-2009,
>   Andrew Aksyonoff
>
> using config file
>   '/opt/intranet3-dev/config/development.sphinx.conf'...
>   indexing index 'computer_delta'...
>   collected 2 docs, 0.0 MB sorted 0.0
>   Mhits, 100.0% done total 2 docs, 62
>   bytes total 0.016 sec, 3724 bytes/sec,
>   120.15 docs/sec total 20 reads, 0.000 sec, 0.0 kb/call avg, 0.0 msec/call
>   avg total 10 writes, 0.000 sec, 0.4
>   kb/call avg, 0.0 msec/call avg
>   rotating indices: succesfully sent
>   SIGHUP to searchd (pid=25435).  =>
>
> computer_type: "Desktop",
>   serial_number: "", unh_id: "", doc_id:
>   "", federal: false, department_id:
>   nil, security_id: nil, purchase_price:
>   nil, purchase_date: "2011-11-05",
>   warranty_expiration: nil, activity_id:
>   nil, condition_id: nil, location_id:
>   nil, operating_system: "Fedora Core",
>   license_sticker_id: nil, comments: "",
>   created_at: "2011-05-19 21:17:55",
>   updated_at: "2011-05-19 21:17:55",
>   user_id: nil, delta: true>

Thanks for the help,

Les

Answer (score 1):

Execute in rails console this code

```
Computer.create! "vendor_id"=>"1", "new_vendor_name"=>"", "model"=>"Hello", "hostname"=>"Hello", "user_id"=>"", "computer_type"=>"Desktop", "serial_number"=>"", "unh_id"=>"", "doc_id"=>"", "federal"=>"0", "department_id"=>"", "new_department_name"=>"", "security_id"=>"", "purchase_price"=>"", "purchase_date"=>"05/11/2011", "warranty_expiration"=>"05/28/2011", "activity_id"=>"", "new_activity_code"=>"", "condition_id"=>"", "new_condition_name"=>"", "location_id"=>"", "operating_system"=>"Fedora Core", "comments"=>""
```

and check what kind of exception is thrown.

Answer (score 1):

```
Open rails console --sandbox
$ computer = Computer.new
$  computer.model = 'abc'
$  computer.new_vendor_name = 'xyz'
$ Keep adding required column values.
$ now try computer.save
# if it prompts true, then your data has been saved successfully if you get false then you have error in your code.

$ computer.errors.full_messages

#above command will list out,where your failed the validations(added in Model).
```